# Wrap current line with PHP tags Brackets (emmet?)

Tags: shortcut, brackets, emmet

I'm trying to find a way to wrap a line with php tags

```
blabla ----> <?php blabla ?>
```

in Brackets, on the press of a shurtcut, like ... let's say 'Ctrl+?'.
I can't seem to achieve that, anyone has an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about any current implementation like this but if you take a look at the shortcut `edit.blockComment` (`Ctrl-Shift-/`), you could mimic this functionality.

Basically you need  to override the `blockComment.prefix` and the `blockComment.suffix` only with the required `<?php` and `?>`.

One entry point could be the following: [LanguageManager.js#setBlockCommentSyntax(prefix, suffix)](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/bc4f6a7c08eb8c1b1a7d6848a3314a18c2d0fd06/src/language/LanguageManager.js#L832)

Comment: So, in my JSON, I would have something like this : `"Ctrl-,":    "edit.blockCommentCustom",` and I should add the new blockCommentCustom somewhere? I'm really lost.

Comment: This would require a lot of editing (add new functionality). It is easier to set the the block comment syntax in the language manager. It is still not trivial, but as an open source project the editor could be modified and recompiled.

Comment: Would you have any example to how I might edit the language manager?

Comment: You should download the whole project and edit the files. After that you can recompile the editor.

Comment: Hmmm ... It seems like I would loose too much time for not much... I thought there would be an easier wat to add custom shortcuts. I'll just use some macros I guess. Thanks for your time anyway !